# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token String.class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I come across using ObjectMapper with String.class for first time.I  tried giving json as string for which got JsonMappingException. Could you please help understand why?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
       String response="{\"response\":\"success\"}";
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Object object = objectMapper.readValue(response, String.class);
        System.out.println(object);
   }
```

Response:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at
>   [Source: {"response":"success"}; line: 1, column: 1]  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:60)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2858)

On just a trial when i pass response as "success", i get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Answer (score 1):

Correct way is to [read it as tree](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(byte[])):

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = om.readTree("{\"response\":\"success\"}");
String response = tree.get("response").asText();
System.out.println(response);
```

outputs: 
`success`

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed json pair where response is a field name and success is a value for this field so you need to create class ResponseDTO

`public class ResponseDto {
    private String response;
    //getter/setter here`

and

```
 Object object = objectMapper.readValue(response, ResponseDTO.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My need is on response which is applicable for String.class

Comment: Well just a simple text in response without Json structure will be ok.

Comment: I tried with just "success" but i got jsonparseException. i have added that too in question

Comment: I meant that you don't need to use ObjectMapper in this case. If your response is just a String you could use it as is.

Comment: You're actually right. I ain't sure. This is existing code. was writing junit for a method which implements this